# Sum columns by key values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
        city             country         city_population
0      New York            USA             8300000
1      London              UK              8900000
2      Paris              France           2100000
3      Chicago             USA             2700000
4      Manchester          UK              510000
5      Marseille          France           860000
```

I want to create a new column `country_population` by calculating a sum of every city for each country. I have tried:

```
df['Country population'] = df['city_population'].sum().where(df['country'])
```

But this won't work, could I have some advise on the problem?

Comment: df.groupby('country')['city_population'].transform('sum')?

Comment: `df.groupby(['country'])['city_population'].sum()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `groupby`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'city': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris', 'Chicago', 'Manchester', 'Marseille'],
    'country': ['USA', 'UK', 'France', 'USA', 'UK', 'France'],
    'city_population': [8_300_000, 8_900_000, 2_100_000, 2_700_000, 510_000, 860_000]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
# group by country, access 'city_population' column, sum
pop = df.groupby('country')['city_population'].sum()
print(pop)
```

output:

```py
country
France     2960000
UK         9410000
USA       11000000
Name: city_population, dtype: int64
```

Appending this Series to the DataFrame. (Arguably discouraged though, since it stores information redundantly and doesn't really fit the structure of the original DataFrame):

```py
# add to existing df
pop.rename('country_population', inplace=True)
# how='left' to preserve original ordering of df
df = df.merge(pop, how='left', on='country')
print(df)
```

output:

```py
         city country  city_population  country_population
0    New York     USA          8300000            11000000
1      London      UK          8900000             9410000
2       Paris  France          2100000             2960000
3     Chicago     USA          2700000            11000000
4  Manchester      UK           510000             9410000
5   Marseille  France           860000             2960000
```

Comment: That seems to work, how would I add country_population as new column?

Comment: Edited original answer

Answer (score 0):

based on @Vaishali's comment, a one-liner

```
df['Country population'] = df.groupby([ 'country']).transform('sum')['city_population']
```